# Multiple Ajax Calls (Only Firefox calling Cross Domain)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to execute 2 ajax calls in a way that, whatever receives from 1st ajax call will the data for second ajax call, working fine on chrome but firefox giving cross domain issues but both files are on same domain.

```
$('.sharer').click(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        url: "sharer.php",
        data: $("#myForm").serializeArray(),
        success: function(response) {
            $(".the-return").html(response); // i am passing .the-return to next ajax call
        } // success
    }); // ajax

    $(".the-return").html2canvas({
        proxy: "src/proxy.php",
        onrendered: function(canvas) {

            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var output = img.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
            var output = encodeURIComponent(img);
            var Parameters = "image=" + output;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'save2.php',
                async: false,
                data: Parameters,
                success: function(datas) {
                    $(".sharer").html("<img src='img/share.png'/>");
                    //$(".imgs").html(datas);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: "firefox giving cross domain issues" — What issues? Does it give you an error message? What does that error message say?

Comment: Cross domain not allowed, Use CORS... Working fine on chrome

Comment: What is the **exact** error message that Firefox reports? Don't paraphrase it.

Comment: Try use any parent class with `find()` like `$('.parentclassname').find(".the-return").html2canvas({`

Comment: 403 Forbidden Error or Sometimes cross domain is not allowed by access-control-allow-origin

Comment: @Zack — You don't even get consistent error messages?! Doesn't the error message include a URL?

Comment: Look in the Net tab of your browser's developer tools. Look at the requests being made and the responses you get. Check they are what you expect.

Comment: I am getting this message now "NetworkError: 403 Forbidden -URL with file name

Comment: Well, that's a server error. So you have to figure why the server is forbidding access to that URL.

Comment: No its not, working fine on chrome

Comment: If i call one ajax call at a time, its working fine but 2 calls are not

Answer (score 0):

Make two functions in you javascript file. Second Ajax call should work with parameter. And second ajax call you should call on .done() of first one. That would work in every browser.

Comment: Can you pls amend my code , i am in learning stage now in jQuery

Answer (score 0):

```
function firstajaxcall() {
   //do all you want before sending first post
    $.ajax({
        url: "url",
        context: document.body,
        data:'data'
    }).done(function(d) {

      //here you place whole ajax2 call

    });
}
```

Comment: I got whats going on, is this possible that can we send whole div as post to php page via jquery ajax, if you see my sharer.php it is returning a div with its contents and i am passing whole div to save2.php, may be something went wrong in these

Comment: can you upload whole project somewhere? I really can't know like this, i am sure i can solve your problem, but not in this way

Answer (score -1):

take you html2Canvas inside success

```
$('.sharer').click(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        url: "sharer.php",
        data: $("#myForm").serializeArray(),
        success: function(response) { 
            $(".the-return").html(response); // i am passing .the-return to next ajax call

            $(".the-return").html2canvas({
        proxy: "src/proxy.php",
        onrendered: function(canvas) {

            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var output = img.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
            var output = encodeURIComponent(img);
            var Parameters = "image=" + output;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'save2.php',
                async: false,
                data: Parameters,
                success: function(datas) {
                    $(".sharer").html("<img src='img/share.png'/>");
                    //$(".imgs").html(datas);
                }
            });
        }
    });

        } // success
    }); // ajax
```